# How do i set up ssl in mysql?

Tags: mysql, ssl, openssl

I am trying to use a SSL connection so that I can use it in a Java application.
I followed the instructions on "Setting Up SSL Certificates and Keys for MySQL" which I found
here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/creating-ssl-certs.html

I don't know what to do from here, I have been reading many tutorials and they all give different steps. My certificates are in the directory

> /home/myuser/newcerts

my mysql version is

> 5.5.35-0ubuntu0.12.04.2

What should my configuration files look like?

How should I start mysql to allow ssl connections?

How should I create a user that REQUIRES SSL?

Both the client and the server are on the same computer.

Comment: Maybe you should start with [using the version 5.5 manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/ssl-connections.html) instead of the 5.0 manual you linked. The chapters "Configuring MySQL for SSL" and "Using SSL Connections" should contain all information you need. If you encounter a specific problem with that, you should ask it. In the current state your question is very broad.

Comment: BTW: Why do you even want to use SSL when client and server are on the same machine? Connections to the same machine can be done via sockets, which are more secure agains outsiders since these connections circumvent the network stack altogether (which should also be a little faster).

Comment: This question appears to belong on another site in the Stack Exchange network because its not about programming. Perhaps [Super User](https://www.superuser.com/) or [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/).